# Quick scan which data (hmac/fernet) can be decrypted with a key?

Tags: hmac, authenticated-encryption

I am designing a secure vault, which stores tens of thousands of encrypted messages and authenticated with Fernet/HMAC, A user query the vault with a key, could I use some kind of index to tell if the key can be used to decrypt any of the stored messages?

Or do I have to try decrypt them one by one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a stupidly simple solution: Create an index of `md5(key)`.

Alternatively, replace `md5` with hash method of your choice.

Answer (score -1):

That design is essentially the reverse of brutal-forcing a cipher key: you are brutal-forcing a key with messages, the time required grows linearly to the size of the vault.

You really should devise a more efficient seeking method.